# Adding known word to Python pyspellchecker with word_frequency.load_words

Tags: python, nlp

I am trying to add a new word to be recognized by pyspellchecker.
The following code:

```
from spellchecker import SpellChecker
spell = SpellChecker(language='es')
spell.word_frequency.load_words('coronavirus')
spell.unknown(['El','coronavirus','marca','nuestros','días'])
```

Produces this output:

```
{'coronavirus'}
```

And the output I expected was:

```
set()
```

...an empty set, as I added the word 'coronavirus' so it should be included in the set of known words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already solved, I missed the brackets.
This is the corrected code:

```
from spellchecker import SpellChecker
spell = SpellChecker(language='es')
spell.word_frequency.load_words(['coronavirus'])
spell.unknown(['El','coronavirus','marca','nuestros','días'])
```

Which has this output:

```
set()
```